# Vbulletin - Adding a padded box around elements

Tags: vbulletin

I'm attempting to add a box (for design purposes) around the threadlist but for whatever reason, it seems to be closing early and I cant for the life of me figure out whats causing it.

http://fantasy-bomb.com/forumdisplay.php?2-Fantasy-Football-Talk

(The theme to use is "Testing")

Its very ugly atm, notice the black rectangle that slightly hides behind the "title/threadstarter" text... It should be covering the entire threadlist and viewing it in firebug shows everything closed properply. I'm at a loss for why its happening.